# Where I can store user data to keep these after an app version update?

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I would like to store the user data in a directory that is not clear after a version update of the app.

Comment: no app data is cleared after version update. You can use any.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to latest version does not affect your data in shared preference. you can save frequently used user data in [shared preference.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)